# Childs of an entity is not receive id after merge of parent entity

Tags: jpa

i have an problem with CascateType.ALL in my WEB application. After update of my entity `Aluno` my child entity `NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira` does not work as expected

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ed44_aluno")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ED44_SQC", sequenceName = "ed44_aluno_ed44_cod_aluno_seq", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class Aluno implements AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ED44_SQC")
    @Column(name = "ed44_cod_aluno")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aluno", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira> linguas;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ed77_linguagem_aluno")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ED77_SQC", sequenceName = "s_ed77_linguagem_aluno", initialValue = 0, allocationSize = 1)
public class NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira implements AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ED77_SQC")
    @Column(name = "ed77_cod_linguagem")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fked77ed44_cod_aluno")
    private Aluno aluno;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("post");      
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        Aluno aluno = manager.find(Aluno.class, 1l);
        aluno.getLinguas().size();
        manager.close();

        NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira nivel = new NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira();
        nivel.setAluno(aluno);
        aluno.addLingua(nivel);

        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.merge(aluno); //update
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        manager.close();

        System.out.println(nivel); // nivel.getId() == null WHY?
    }
```

my output:

after find method call:

> select aluno where id = 1 (edited, long query)

after merge method call:

> select nextval ('s_ed77_linguagem_aluno')

after commit:

> insert into ed77_linguagem_aluno (fked77ed44_cod_aluno, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_ent, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_esc, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_fal, fked77tg22_cod_nivel_lingua_le, fked77tg33_cod_lingua, ed77_cod_linguagem) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

end of code:

> NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira [id=null, aluno=Aluno [id=1, codigoInep=null, codigoNis=null, nome=FULANO DE TAL EDITADO 8, apelido=null, nascimento=null, nDependentes=null, mae=null, pai=null, conjuge=null, fotoSrc=null, dataCadastro=2014-05-23 15:46:43.586, endereco=null, contato=null, documentacao=null], lingua=null, escreve=null, entende=null, fala=null, leitura=null]

The problem is: WHY my entity NivelAlunoLinguaEstrangeira dont receive your ID?

Answer (score 0):

Because `merge` returns the modified value, it doesn't touch the argument as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29).

So you need to keep the reference like so:

```
manager = factory.createEntityManager();
manager.getTransaction().begin();
aluno = manager.merge(aluno); //update
manager.getTransaction().commit();
manager.close();
```